# What's the version of Appium Java-client that will auto prefix "Appium" to follow W3C protocol

Tags: java, appium, saucelabs, appium-java

I am trying to update my scripts to follow W3C Protocol for Appium tests.

Can't find which version of Appium java-client will automatically prefix "Appium" keyword to the capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that starting from `8.0.0-beta` Appium java-client forcibly converts capabilities to W3C format with adding `appium:` prefix to all unprefixed not defined in WebDriver W3C doc capability names.

*8.0.0-beta2* is the latest available version which do this.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/8.0.0-beta2

*8.0.0-beta* should also work.